# SQL Server 2005: SSIS - Import macro enabled spreadsheet into database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

SQL Server 2005 doesn't allow to import macro enabled spreadsheet, when we select excel as provider and give this macro enabled spreadsheet then it gives file type error.

Can anyone advise if they have tried to import macro enabled spreadsheet using SSIS in sql server.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple solution require to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable :
http://devinknightsql.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/using-excel-macro-xlsm-enabled-files-in-ssis/